# cassandra server takes too much time for turns into up

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a cassandra cluster of having single data center with 2 nodes.Two nodes are in two racks.First node having 6.6Gib and Second node having 5.9 Gib.Second node often turns down.When i restart the server it takes alot of time to turns into up.So can anyone help me out of this situation

Comment: Could you explain further. You say second node turns down often, is this expected or does it crash? How long is "alot of time"? Can you see anything in the logs?